# What are the circumstances of what Obito the Sharingan used against Konan and the Kakashi's Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

Obito lost a Sharingan after using Izanagi against Konan. And now its shown that he gave Mangekyo Sharingan to Kakashi in both his eyes. What's the connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have seen the fight between **Tobi (Obito)** and **Konan**, he actually used his left eye which he had given to **Kakashi**. So the Sharingan he used for Izanagi was of the other (**Uchiha**).

[image: Tobi (Obito) vs Konan using left eye for Izanagi]

Also, Obito gave Kakashi his Sharingan (the right one) and Kakashi already has the left Sharingan, so he has both and talking about Mangekyo, Kakashi has already awakened that power.